# Proper use of Accessors in C#

Tags: c#

I have been learning C# on and off for a few years now (I mainly use C++) and in that time, I have been manually coding in the `get` and `set` for each field.

I recently read about Accessors and how if you code it like so...

```
    private string _colour;
    public string Colour
    {
        set
        {
            _colour = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _colour;
        }
    }
```

Assigning and Obtaining values to/from Colour, will execute the `set` or `get` method to use modify or obtain the value from _colour. However, I am a bit unclear on how this works. Doesn't this use up more than normal memory? Aren't we creating 2 string field sized objects in memory?

I tried just using the Colour instead of both Colour and _colour, and changing the `get` and `set` blocks to modify the field itself, but that always ends up in an infinite loop.

Are we better off doing the way shown above? Or to make our own `get` and `set` methods?

Comment: **By the way:** Your code can be simplified. You can just write `public string Colour {get; set;}` and remove the private variable `private string _colour;`

Comment: It only creates one memory allocation - `private string _colour`. The way you have it is fine.

Comment: @KobyDouek - Which doesn't answer the question - and perhaps makes the issue more confusing for the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity That was a **comment**. I was not attempting to answer. If I was, It wouldnt have been a comment, right?

Comment: If you code it using `public string Colour { get; set; }` the compiler effectively expands it to your code anyway.

Comment: @KobyDouek - Fair enough, but it's worth making sure you're explaining why you're making the comment as in this case it can be a bit misleading.

Comment: @Enigmativity Fair enough, I added a "by the way".

Comment: Why the down-votes on this question? It seems perfectly fine for someone to ask this.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am used to the downvotes on what is a perfectly fine question, perfectly fine to me at least.

Thank you for all the info guys!

Comment: @Enigmativity Too many down votes are because of personal preference and impatience rather than applying simple guidelines, namely **[down votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) are for questions which are _egregiously_ sloppy or off topic.  NOT for beginner questions.  NOT for non-English-speaker questions.** Meta discussions of this problem are opinionated rants... there is too much indecision about what to do with new posters that have not yet masted the "perfect" question. Like you, I've started asking why in the comments more often. Prepare for backlash though.

Comment: @CPerkins, I don't post here very often. Having said that, is it really needed to shoot for the "perfect" question? In my eyes, if the admins spent less time trying to get us to post perfect questions, maybe the site would be able to handle the allegations of it being filled with rude people.

Just my honest opinion.

Comment: @BryanDouglas - I think the site works very well as is.

Comment: @BryanDouglas  No, it is not needed to post perfect questions.  That was my point.  But more often than before I see many reasonable questions voted down.  There is discussion of this on the [Meta website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com), but not good solution. Too many don't respect the guidelines and just vote without really considering the best reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Aren't we creating 2 string field sized objects in memory?

No. `Colour` is *not* a field. It's a property, which is different. The compiler implements the properties *only* as the two `get`/`set` methods. There is no new memory needed. If you want, you can abuse the feature to just declare two strangely-named methods with weird assignment/read syntax to call them. That's all they are.

Additionally, for simple properties, you can also avoid manually creating the backing field:

```
public string Colour {get;set;}
```

That creates an *auto-implemented* property, which still uses `get` and `set` methods behind the scenes, and gives you the nice property semantics without having to manually write the code.

You can even have properties without their own backing field at all:

```
//auto-implemented property describing the location of your object
public Point Location {get; set;}

//"shortcut"/convenience properties that rely entirely on backing fields elsewhere, with no new memory of their own
public int X 
{
    get { return Location.X; }
    set { Location.X = value; }
}
public int Y
{
    get { return Location.Y; }
    set { Location.Y = value; }
}
```

Comment: "You can even have properties with**out** their own backing field at all"